How do I remove .aab file that I uploaded in Android Explorer Bundle and Released in Internal Testing?
I excidently uploaded and released in Internal Testing a version that Version Code is too big from previous ones. So I would like to remove it but I can not because it's status seems active in Release Status in Android Explorer Bundle.
Is there a way to remove this .aab file from Android Explorer Bundle? I would like to continue Version Code 33, 34, 35 etc.
I tried to remove Android Explorer Bundle build but since Release Status is active I can not remove it.

You can't remove any uploaded aab or apk files from Google Play Console. You have to continue your versioning from the last uploaded.

To clarify: yes, you can remove them as long as they haven't been published. There's a "Delete app bundle" option that shows up in App bundle explorer, but only if it's not attached to a release (like if you draft and discard the draft). The button is close to impossible to spot and blends in with the rest of the UI completely, I can never find it when I need it. https://i.imgur.com/Mzx3UCi.png
